# What are the benefits of type inference?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm started to learn F#, and I noticed that one of the major differences in syntax from C# is that type inference is used much more than in C#. This is usually presented as one of the benefits of F#. Why is type inference presented as benefit?

Imagine, you have a class hierarchy and code that uses different classes from it. Strong typing allows you quickly detect which classes are used in any method.
With type inference it will not be so obvious and you have to use hints to understand, which class is used. Are there any techniques that exist to make F# code more readable with type inference?

Comment: This is sort of a broad question @eternity.  Maybe you can edit your question to something a bit more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question assumes that you are using object-oriented programming (e.g. complex class hierarchies) in F#. While you can certainly do that, using OO concepts is mainly useful for interoperability or for wrapping some F# functionality in a .NET library.

**Understanding code.** Type inference becomes much more useful when you write code in the functional style. It makes code shorter, but also helps you understand what is going on. For example, if you write `map` function over list (the `Select` method in LINQ):

```
let map f list = 
  seq { for el in list -> f el }
```

The type inference tells you that the function type is:

```
val map : f:('a -> 'b) -> list:seq<'a> -> seq<'b>
```

This matches our expectations about what we wanted to write - the argument `f` is a function turning values of type `'a` into values of type `'b` and the `map` function takes a list of `'a` values and produces a list of `'b` values. So you can use the type inference to easily check that your code does what you would expect.

**Generalization.** Automatic generalization (mentioned in the comments) means that the above code is automatically as reusable as possible. In C#, you might write:

```
 IEnumerable<int> Select(IEnumerable<int> list, Func<int, int> f) {
   foreach(int el in list) 
     yield return f(el);
 }
```

This method is not generic - it is `Select` that works only on collections of `int` values. But there is no reason why it should be restricted to `int` - the same code would work for any types. The type inference mechanism helps you discover such generalizations.

**More checking.** Finally, thanks to the inference, the F# language can more easily check more things than you could if you had to write all types explicitly. This applies to many aspects of the language, but it is best demonstrated using units of measure:

```
let l = 1000.0<meter>
let s = 60.0<second>
let speed = l/s
```

The F# compiler infers that `speed` has a type `float<meter/second>` - it understands how units of measure work and infers the type including unit information. This feature is really useful, but it would be hard to use if you had to write all units by hand (because the types get long). In general, you can use more precise types, because you do not have to (always) type them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, especially for the explanation about the automatic generalization - I did not aware about this feature.